# How to insert 0 or 1 in a database field if checkbox inside the gridview is checked?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview, checkbox

I have a gridview on my web form and I have taken checkbox in the template field of my gridview. I want that if the checkbox is checked inside the gridview, it will insert 1 in my database column and if it is unchecked then it should insert 0 i.e. by default the field should be inserted with 0.
I have tried doing this-
My aspx page-

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridMain" runat="server" Width="1000px" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Student Name">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblname" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Enable/Disable">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkenbl" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                        oncheckedchanged="chkenbl_CheckedChanged" />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>' Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

My cs page-

```
public void show()
{
    try
    {
        dt = g1.return_dt("select id,name from tbl_data_show where en_dis='0' order by name");
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            adsource = new PagedDataSource();
            adsource.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
            adsource.PageSize = 5;
            GridMain.DataSource = adsource;
            GridMain.DataBind();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.ToString());
    }
}
protected void chkenbl_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridMain.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox chk = sender as CheckBox;
        if (chk.Checked)
        {
            try
            {
                //Label lblid = (Label)GridMain.FindControl("Label1");
                Label lblid = new Label();
                lblid.Text = GridMain.FindControl("Label1").ToString();
                rows=g1.ExecDB("insert into tbl_data_show(en_dis) values('1') where id="+lblid.Text);
                if (rows > 0)
                {
                    Response.Write("Rows Effected Successfull.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Label lblid1 = (Label)GridMain.FindControl("Label1");
            Label lblid1 = new Label();
            lblid1.Text = GridMain.FindControl("Label1").ToString();
            rows=g1.ExecDB("insert into tbl_data_show(en_dis) values('0') where id="+lblid1.Text);
            if (rows > 0)
            {
                Response.Write("Rows Effected Successfull.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please guide me where I am going wrong. I am getting this exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.".

Comment: Don't do this: `rows=g1.ExecDB("insert into tbl_data_show(en_dis) values('1') where id="+lblid.Text);` use parameterized sql. Have you debugged your code? Does it throw an exception? What is the expected behaviour and what is the observed behaviour?

Comment: So what's the exact problem you're experiencing? Is there exception? What's the value of lblid.Text in runtime? What's the type of id in DB (if it is varchar, you should wrap the value with quotes). BTW, Convert.ToInt32(bool) can decrease amount of your code.

Comment: @DGibbs: Yes please check my updated question. I have mentioned what exception I am getting.

Comment: @d_z: Please check my question friend. I have updated my question. Please guide me where I am doing wrong?

Comment: @Omi, Which statement produces the exception?

Comment: @d_z: Error is reflecting in
`Label lblid = new Label();
                    lblid.Text = GridMain.FindControl("Label1").ToString();
                    rows=g1.ExecDB("insert into tbl_data_show(en_dis) values('1') where id="+lblid.Text);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, now after getting some details I can tell that:
1) Your checkbox has autopostback=true which will cause post back on every checkbox click. In the code-behind cycle throw all rows and update, therefore you'll update all rows every time you click any checkbox.
2) For getting the Label.Text value you could try something like this:

```
CheckBox chkStatus = (CheckBox)sender;
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)chkStatus.NamingContainer;
Label lbl = (Label)row.FindControl("Label1");
string lblTxt = lbl.Text;
```

Or you could add custom attribute to your checkbox (rid="<%# Eval("id") %>") and to get its value instead of having hidden label:

```
string id = ((CheckBox)sender).Attributes["rid"].ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot friend. It was really nice talking to u. I have learnt a lot from u guys :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(chkenbl.IsChecked)
{
  insert 1..
}
else
{
   insert 0..
}
```